# sum looping by group php

Tags: php, codeigniter, sum

i have tbl area

```
area_kode | area_name 
101         area jak
102         area band
103         area pal
```

and i have tbl barang

```
id | kode | name |  price
 1   101    gelas   2000
 2   101    botol   4000
 3   102    celana  4000
```

model :

```
  $db = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_area")->result();
  return $db;

  $db = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_barang")->result();
  return $db;
```

my controller

```
 public function area_get(){
        $data = $this->model_area->db_area();  
        $arr = array();
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            $area  = $this->model_barang->db_barang($value->kode);  
            $arr[] = $value->area_name;
        }
        echo "<pre>", print_r($area);      
    }
```

how to make a sum by area ? I made like the code below the name has not been successful

i want output like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "area": "area jak",
            "kode": "101",
            "total": "6000", //sum
        },
        {
            "area": "area ban",
            "kode": "102",
            "total": "4000", //sum
        },
        {
            "area": "area pal",
            "kode": "103",
            "total": "0", //if area no data 
        },

    }
```

I hope here can help

Comment: What raw query has been made you to get desired results?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not loop over the items and sum up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, with only mysql query

```
  select A.area_kode code, sum(B.price) total
  from tbl_area A
    left join tbl_barang B
     on A.area_kode = B.kode
  group by A.area_kode
```